# Implemented Stripe v3 card element in my checkout and jquery stopped working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have recently began switching over to using stripe card elements in my checkout form and I have gotten the stripe elements to show up on the page correctly but I noticed than when I got this working, now all my Jquery calls on that form stopped working. Does this have something to do with Stripe? I am wondering if something with the Stripe injecting the card elements prevents the document from ever triggering a 'ready' state with Jquery. My code is below, I could really use some insight on this as I have reached the end of my knowledge on this and cant seem to find a way to make this work. (note: I am using jquery to update hidden fields on the form that passes which form version the user has filled out, one form has two additional fields. The Jquery on the page also dynamically updates the "Total" that is displayed on the screen. The actual total is entered using the same function, but is called after validation on the backend.)

here is my _order_form.html.erb

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 mb-md-0 mb-5">
        <%= form_for @order do |f| %>

           
        <%= f.hidden_field 'referred_by_school', { id: "referBySchool" } %>

           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="md-form mb-0">
                        <%= f.label :customer_name, "Your Name *", class: "control-label" %><br />
                        <%= f.text_field :customer_name, class: "form-control" %>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="md-form mb-0">
                        <%= f.label :email, "Email *", class: "control-label" %><br />
                        <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        <% if locals[:buy_method] == "group"%>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="md-form mb-0">
                        <%= f.label :student_name, "Student Name *", class: "control-label" %><br />
                        <%= f.text_field :student_name, class: "form-control" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="md-form mb-0">
                        <%= f.label :school_name, "School or Group Name *", class: "control-label" %><br />
                        <%= f.text_field :school_name, class: "form-control"%>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <br>
        
        <% end %>
        <div class="col-md-2">Shipping Info</div>
    
            <div class="col-md-6">
            
                <div class="shipping-container">
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                    <%= f.label :street_address, "Street Address *", class: "control-label" %><br />
                                    <%= f.text_field :street_address, class: "form-control" %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                <%= f.label :city, "City *", class: "control-label" %><br />
                                <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control" %>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                <%= f.label :state, "State *", class: "control-label" %><br />
                                <%= f.select :state, ['AL', 'AK', 'AS', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'DC', 'FM', 'FL', 'GA', 'GU', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MH', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'MP', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PW', 'PA', 'PR', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VI', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY' ], class: "form-control"%>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                <%= f.label :zip_code, "Zip code *", class: "control-label" %><br />
                                <%= f.text_field :zip_code, class: "form-control" %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="md-form mb-0">
                        <%= f.check_box :email_permission, checked: "checked", checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false %>
                        <%= f.label :email_permission, class: "checkbox-inline", class: "control-label" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>

           <br>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="md-form mb-0">
                        <%= f.label :number_books, value: "Number of books to purchase *", class: "control-label" %><br />
                        <% if locals[:buy_method] == "group" %>
                            <%= f.text_field :number_books, class: "form-control", id: "groupNumberBooks" %>
                        <% elsif locals[:buy_method] == "individual" %>
                            <%= f.text_field :number_books, class: "form-control", id: "individualNumberBooks" %>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <% if locals[:buy_method] == "group" %>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <%= f.label :total, value: "Total: $", class: "control-label" %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <%= f.label :total, id: "groupTotal", class: "form-control", value: 0 %>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% end %>

            <% if locals[:buy_method] == "group" %>
                <div class="row" id="card_field1">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div id="card-element-1"><!--Stripe.js injects the Card Element--></div>
                            <button id="submit-1">
                                <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
                                <span id="button-text">Pay</span>
                            </button>
                            <p id="card-errors-1" role="alert"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% end %>

            <% if locals[:buy_method] == "individual" %>
                <div class="row">
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= f.label :total, value: "Total: $", class: "control-label" %> <br>
                        <%= f.label :total, id: "individualTotal", class: "form-control", value: 0 %>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            <% end %>

            <% if locals[:buy_method] == "individual" %>
                <div class="row" id="card_field2">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div id="card-element-2"><!--Stripe.js injects the Card Element--></div>
                            <button id="submit-2">
                                <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
                                <span id="button-text">Pay</span>
                            </button>
                            <p id="card-errors-2" role="alert"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% end %>
            
        
               
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
// Create a Stripe client.
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_***************************************');

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements1 = stripe.elements();
var elements2 = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card1 = elements1.create('card', {style: style});
var card2 = elements2.create('card', {style: style});
</script>

<script>
// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card1.mount('#card-element-1');
card2.mount('#card-element-2');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card1.on('change', function(event) {
  var displayError1 = document.getElementById('card-errors-1');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError1.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError1.textContent = '';
  }
});

card2.on('change', function(event) {
  var displayError2 = document.getElementById('card-errors-2');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError2.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError2.textContent = '';
  }
});
</script>

<script>
// Handle form submission.
var form1 = document.getElementById('new_order');
form1.addEventListener('submit-1', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error.
      var errorElement1 = document.getElementById('card-errors-1');
      errorElement1.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});

// Handle form submission.
var form2 = document.getElementById('new_order');
form2.addEventListener('submit-1', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error.
      var errorElement2 = document.getElementById('card-errors-1');
      errorElement2.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});
</script>

<script>    
// Submit the form with the token ID.
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form1 = document.getElementById('new_order');
  var hiddenInput1 = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput1.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput1.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput1.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form1.appendChild(hiddenInput1);

  // Submit the form
  form1.submit();
};
  
</script>

<script>
// Submit the form with the token ID.
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form2 = document.getElementById('new_order');
  var hiddenInput2 = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput2.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput2.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput2.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form2.appendChild(hiddenInput2);

  // Submit the form
  form2.submit();

};
 
</script>
```

and here is my application.js with my jquery for the form.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#groupNumberBooks").on("input", function () {
    var price = 20;
    var numBooks = document.getElementById("groupNumberBooks").value;
    var total = parseFloat(price) * numBooks;

    if (!isNaN(total)) document.getElementById("groupTotal").innerHTML = total;
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#individualNumberBooks").on("input", function () {
    var price = 20;
    var numBooks = document.getElementById("individualNumberBooks").value;
    var total = parseFloat(price) * numBooks;

    if (!isNaN(total)) document.getElementById("individualTotal").innerHTML = total;
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#groupButton").on("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("referBySchool").value = true;
    });
  });


$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#individualButton").on("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("referBySchool").value = false;
  });
});
```

All of my jquery was working yesterday, and now, after implementing this I cannot figure out why it is no longer working. I tried removing the stripe elements and this did not restore the Jquery to a working state either... which has me really confused now!

I may just switch back to my master branch and test that just to check my sanity XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with wrapping your code in jQuery.ready callbacks and attaching handlers directly to your elements is that it will not work when Turbolinks replaces the page contents with ajax.

Instead you want to create delegated event handlers that capture the event as it bubbles up to the top of the DOM.

You can do this by attaching the event handler to the document itself instead of each element and by passing a second argument to jQuery.on which acts as a filter:

```
$(document).on("input", "#groupNumberBooks", function () {
  let price = 20;
  let total = parseFloat(price) * this.value;
  if (!isNaN(total)) document.getElementById("groupTotal").innerHTML = total;
}).on("input", "#individualNumberBooks", function () {
  let price = 20;
  let total = parseFloat(price) * this.value;
  if (!isNaN(total)) document.getElementById("individualTotal").innerHTML = total;
}).on("click", "#groupButton", function () {
  document.getElementById("referBySchool").value = true;
}).on("click", "#individualButton", function () {
  document.getElementById("referBySchool").value = false;
});
```

This also uses the fact that almost all the jQuery methods return the jQuery object they where called on and thus are chainable.